At what altitude is the ISP of a rocket in our atmospehre usually defined? Why is the vaccuum ISP not used for performance evaluations instead?
If we are defining ISP (Ceff/g) at sea level, wouldn´t it be easier to just use the ISP in vaccuum and avoid the varying but common atmospheric pressure parameter (Po) in the thrust equation and hence in the equation for the effective exhaust velocity?
Ceff = (mdotWe + (Pe-Po)Ae )/F

IIRC, vacuum ISP is used for vacuum engines, sea level for ones used down low, both are given for engines that go from sea level all the way above Karman line.

ISP in vacuum doesn't help get you to vacuum.


At what altitude is the ISP of a rocket in our atmosphere usually defined?

The most correct answer here is in vacuum, though, as you note, sea-level values are often reported as well. I wouldn't be too surprised to see values reported at other back-pressures if it made sense for the mission (i.e. if the engine is planned to operate at a particular altitude).

Why is the vacuum Isp not used for performance evaluations instead?

It absolutely is. For anybody doing performance calculations, they will, of course, use the true Isp (corrected for back-pressure). More likely they would just directly use the thrust.
The truth of the matter is that Isp is a bulk performance metric. Its main purpose in rigorous mission design is to give a rough idea of engine efficiency. To this end, the reporting of sea-level values makes perfect sense: giving a rough idea of the engines performance at elevated back-pressure.
